# How to convert the BigDecimal number to a double number without losing any number

Tags: java

**This is the big number  : 254256628887691648979255764287710332682151112652865.9681904928382641667798422015028931598796582694627540510
 I want to convert to a double number without losing precision**

Comment: 254256628887691648979255764287710332682151112652865.9681904928382641667798422015028931598796582694627540510 convert to double    2.5425662888769167E50

Comment: `double` values do not have that much precision.

Comment: `double` has 64 bits of information. The value you want to represent has significantly more information than that. You simply can't do what you want. It's like asking to get any integer from 1 to a million in a byte...

Comment: A `double` has 15 to 17 significant decimal digits precision. It *cannot* store more than that. It's **impossible**. Cannot be done.

Comment: Can we reverse process convert 2.5425662888769167E50 to
254256628887691648979255764287710332682151112652865.96819049‌​28382641667798422015‌​02893159879658269462‌​7540510

Comment: If you ask me to print out a 50 page document, and I give you the first fifteen pages, can you recreate the other 35 pages out of thin air?

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `double` and not lose precision. You need to use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead

```
BigDecimal d  = new BigDecimal("254256628887691648979255764287710332682151112652865.9681904928382641667798422015028931598796582694627540510");
```

Comment: I want to convert this number to without losing precision

Comment: Convert to what? There is nothing bigger than `BigDecimal` in Java SE library.